# PM2 cluster mode multi instance not working (with Next.js server)

Tags: node.js, deployment, next.js, pm2

I am trying to deploy a Next.js(`next@12.0.8`) application on a production Linux server, Daemonize and load-balance it via `pm2` npm module.

When I start the application in `fork` mode all works fine.

The problem arises when I start it in a cluster mode with 4 instances.
In this case only one instance is running and the rest of the instances are with "**status=errored**".

**Node.js** version = **v16.13.2**

**Next.js** version = **12.0.8**

**pm2** version = **5.1.2**

and here is the ***ecosystem.config.js*** :

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name   : "csr-next",
    cwd: '/home/ruby/node/next-gen/',
    script: 'npm',
    args: 'start',
    exec_mode : "cluster",
    instances: 4
  }],
};
```

Here is a demo [video](https://youtu.be/yAyC-EEtX7k) to demonstrate.

Checked the CPU(s) number on the host machine via `$lscpu`

```
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              4
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-3
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  2
```

Comment: I saw in your video that the first (`0`) app always works as intended and, `1, 2, and 3` are the ones that give you issues. Have you checked to see how Next.js handles port bindings? This might help as well: https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/issues/1510#issuecomment-131145772

Comment: This might also help: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/10675#discussioncomment-590